# Fill horizontal space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the green area here to fill the entire horizontal white area between the green and the blue area.
The problem is that I don't know what I should put on it's `width` attribute, currently it is `500px`.

```
<article id="chat">
</article>
<aside id="channel-attendees">
</aside>
```

`chat` is the left bar, `channel-attendees` the right one.

```
#chat {
    background: green;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}

#channel-attendees {
    background: blue;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you express width with percentages? I.E. 80% (green), 20% (blue)?

Comment: I think it is/looks better, if the sidebar always maintains the same width (just like the facebook-sidebar for example)

Comment: Ok, then some solution might be to catch with JS width of window, substract 200px, and apply result to green field :)

Comment: @poitroae: You have no idea who downvoted the question. You know who commented, and you know that someone downvoted. It's not a good idea to assume they're the same person. Usually, they aren't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay, sorry me then if it wasn't you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use `width` try this:

```
#chat {
  background: green;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the green width, to 90% and change the blue one to float left width 10%,this should then work on all types of monitors ;)

```
#chat {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 90%;
}


#channel-attendees {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Nope, I want it to be exactly 200px wide :D

Comment: Oh 1 second my bad ^^ If you want the whole background to be green then just set the background to be green and use absolute position on the blue and set the width to 200px as shown by "mattedgod" above! 
If you don't want the whole background to be green wrap in a div just set that div background to be green

Comment: Well, why don't you say so in question? ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the green area to be flexible and blue area with fixed width the you just need to remove float and width from green block, also you need to add margin-right to a green block with value = blue block width.

```
#chat {
background: green;  
height: 500px;   
margin-right: 200px;
}
```

And put the blue block before green.

```
 <body>
  <header>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/icon256.png"></a>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="user">
                <img id="user-avatar" src="img/avatar.jpg">
                <span id="user-name">Michael</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="channels">
    </div>
    <aside id="channel-attendees">
    </aside><article id="chat">
    </article> 
</body>
```